# pass a data key value from a json post request to routes to controller

Tags: php, jquery, json, laravel, laravel-5

my json post request has a data key named "id", now how im going to pass it from routes to my controller?

my json post request

```
$.post("/employees", {id:"1"}, function(response){
if(response.success)
{
    var branchName = $('#branchname').empty();
    $.each(response.employees, function(){
        $('<option/>', {
            value:$(this).user_no,
            text:$(this).firstname
        }).appendTo(branchName);
    });
}
}, 'json');
```

as you can see from my json post request i have put a key value name id

my routes

```
Route::post('employees', [
    'as' => 'employees', 'uses' => 'mot@getemployee'
]);
```

and my controller

```
public function getemployee($id){
        $employees = employees::where("branch_no", $id)->lists('firstname', 'user_no');
        return response()->json(['success' => true, 'employees' => $employees]);
}
```

as you can see, I have an argument $id, it supposedly, its where the key value named id from the json post request will be put and be used from the query stuff.

Comment: Since you're using `$.post`, should you use `$id = $_POST['id'];` inside your function and not treating it as a parameter?

Comment: The more important question - that helped? hhh

Comment: @OfirBaruch: thank you for the answer. can you look at my script? in my chrome console, it display all the json reponse i get. I have a select tag with an id of "branchname" where the json reponse will be put in but it doesnt work. when i view the page source, my select tag has been populated by an empty option tag like "<select id="branchname"><option></option><option></option><option></option></select>" any ideas, clues about this please?

Comment: Do you have a live version of the script?

Comment: sadly, I dont have. but I have no errors showing in my console and I can see in my console all the response i get from the json post request i sent but only when displaying the response data i get is not working, i even tried to do like "alert($(this).user_no);" but it popups "undefined" any clues, ideas?

Comment: No problem, can you please add the response you see in your browser's console  to your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77541/discussion-between-ofir-baruch-and-code-demon).

Comment: For gods sake you are using a framework and should use Request::input('id'); instead of $_POST

Comment: solve now thank you @OfirBaruch for the big help. your a life saver :)

Comment: @KhanShahrukh: when using Request::input('id'); instead of $_POST i get 500 Internal Server Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using `$.post` in your jQuery code, the `{id: ...}` parameter passed as a POST data, which means that instead of having:

```
public function getemployee($id){
```

You should have:

```
public function getemployee() {
 $id = (int)$_POST['id']; //notice that int casting
```

@KhanShahrukh has a good point. Consider using the following instead of the traditional POST variable:

```
<?php 
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Request;
....
....
class ... extends ... {
  public function ...() {
    if(Request::ajax()) { //Prevent direct access
      $id = Request::input('id;);
```

Regarding the second issue (which mentioned in the comment), `$(this)` won't refer to the object. In order to access the object's properties, you should add parameters to the `function()` in your `$.each` function. ([Manual](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/))

So instead of:

```
$.each(response.employees, function(){
    $('<option/>', {
        value:$(this).user_no,
        text:$(this).firstname
```

You should have:

```
$.each(response.employees, function(firstname, user_no){
    $('<option/>', {
        value: user_no,
        text: firstname
```

Comment: thank you, i have another issue, i added "lastname" on the list "$employees = mot_users::where("branch_no", $id)->lists('user_no', 'lastname', 'firstname');" and tried to display it with "$.each(response.employees, function(user_no, firstname, lastname){
            $('<option/>', {
                value:firstname + " " + lastname,
                text:user_no
            }).appendTo(branchName);
        });"

but it always show me only the lastname on the option text and not the combination of firstname and lastname. any ideas and clues?

Comment: So you need to pass an array of objects where each object is an employee with 3 properties. I don't know if `->lists()` is what you're looking for if this is the case. What's the output of `console.debug(response.emp...` ?

Comment: in the console log, i got only the use_no and the lastname.

Comment: it should also send the firstname and not only the user_no and the lastname. any clues, ideas?

Comment: `lists()` can't handle more than 2 parameters if i'm not mistaken, so - or you'll have to use the regular `get()` or you'll have to pass only 2 values.

Comment: i see. how to make it using get()?

Comment: You can follow the example in the manual as your usage request is pretty simple: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#selects

Comment: given that this question is tagged with laravel 5, it's preferable to DI in `Illuminate\Http\Request` into a controller method, then get the input with `$request->input('id')`, rather than using the facade. [see the third example here in the laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers)